# AWS load balancer IIS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis

I have configured app load balancer on amazon. Set up DNS LB to route 53 with alias for A. Behind LB i have 2 instances with IIS. If i set up 2 sites on both instances, balancer automatically balance client by rotation
(as i know round robin). But, if i turn off site on IIS in one instance, load balancer continue go to that instance and if i go to exapmle.com i will have one time worked site and if refresh the page i will have error (because site turned off in IIS). Could you please tell me, how can i set up load balance to route traffic in working instance if one of them not working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Load balancers continue to distribute the traffic on healthy servers. If it is not happening in your case, I would recheck the health check configuration under Target Groups.

You need to modify the port/path so that health checks start failing once the site is turned off. Only then, the load balancer will pass all traffic to healthy host, not the unhealthy host

Comment: Do you mean i need to have target group for each site?

Comment: If i have site on IIS example.com, what should i past in "path" in health check?

Comment: Rather than path, you can do a TCP check on port 80 - the most basic check. It should fail if you turn off the site.

Comment: I can use http or https. TCP is missing

Comment: http checks for 80, https for 443, go for http

Answer (score 0):

What does the LB health checks say? If the back-end instances are not listening on the health check port then LB marks it as unhealthy and stops forwarding requests to it. If you are using Application loadbalancer then I think you can get the health check status within the target groups associated with the loadbalancer.

Comment: Do you mean i need to have target group for each site?

Comment: If i have site on IIS example.com, what should i past in "path" in health check?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html provides information on how to configure health check